# What is the meaning of underscore in _ = WriteItems(channel.Writer, count, delay);

Tags: c#, system.threading.channels

I'm reading about SignalR and I have found code:

```
  public ChannelReader<int> Counter(int count, int delay)
{
    var channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>();

    // We don't want to await WriteItems, otherwise we'd end up waiting 
    // for all the items to be written before returning the channel back to
    // the client.
    _ = WriteItems(channel.Writer, count, delay);

    return channel.Reader;
}
```

What is the meaning of underscore? Is it variable?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards

Comment: Where did you find this code? Is it in SignalR's source code? Although it appears to be a discard, it also appears to be completely unnecessary. You could just not assign the result value to any variable/discard.

Comment: @mason https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @Zet The quality of the more expository MSDN pages is....not ideal. They often write code that ignores recommendations they've given in other places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong but it looks like a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) to me.